# 'Best score' in XGBOOST Regression

Tags: regression, gradient-descent, optimization, boosting

I'm running an XGBRegressor for parameter optimization as below:

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(nthread=10)
clf = pipeline.Pipeline([('xgb', xgb_model)])
param_grid = {'xgb__max_depth': [1,2,3],    
              'xgb__learning_rate': [0.2,0.3,0.4],  
              'xgb__n_estimators': [40,45,50]   
             }  

model = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, verbose=10, n_jobs=1,
                         iid=True, refit=True, cv=10)

model.fit(X, Y_log)
```

I see few 'scores' listed (can be +/-) in the console out of which the 'Best score' is chosen.

I want to understand what this 'score' is in a Regression setting, and how it is calculated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the GridSearchCV you may choose your scoring type, ie "explained variation", "area under the ROC", etc...

The "sklearn model evaluation" module is highly complex and allows to choose between a complex set of evaluation approaches.

By default, the scoring method is set to None, taking the default estimator's scoring method if available.

When training a model with the train method, xgboost will provide the evals_result  property that returns a dictionary which "eval_metric" key returns the evaluation metric used.

Also, when fitting with your booster, if you pass the eval_set value, then you may call the evals_result() method to get the same information.

For more details and ways of exploring this, I suggest you visit xgboost's API page and sklearn model evaluation pages on Internet.